# Zend Framework Application Going white after application->bootstrap()->run()

Tags: zend-framework, wsod

I have never used zend framework before today. Though I know PHP my client gave this site to me which seems to be stuck.

I can't figure out what is wrong here. I tried these-

- I have enabled error reporting and writing some junk code on `index.php` shows some error to prove it. but I still dont see anything.
- Server has Zendguard enabled
- On the `index.php` file everything works to the point of this function,

> $application->bootstrap()->run();

can anyone give me a pointer , what could possibly cause this white screen of death? or at least show me where to look next?

Comment: you should try this to see your error first on your code. `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);`

Answer (score 0):

Open `youapp/application/configs/application.ini`

Find this lines in `[production]` and `[development : production]` stages

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
```

and change `0` to `1` now try again..